# How add a file inside a jar into the classpath?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar that's pulled into other projects as a gradle dependency. It has an XML file in it (for HBase) that needs to be at the beginning of the classpath so it's picked up when the HBase driver is loaded.

Since it's inside the jar file, how would I pass its path to the URLClassLoader?

I know I can add to the class path by doing something like:

```
private static void addSoftwareLibrary(File file) throws Exception {
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
}
```

but, how would I:

1. Pass the file's location inside the jar to this?
2. Prepend instead of append it to the path?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it at build time. pack it inside the Jar
2. You can create wrapper script to launch. It takes some parameter as an input and manipulates classpath entries before launching Java